# Getting Object not set to an instance - Directory Services

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to retrieve the manager email base on a user.

I did investigated about this, and I found this code but getting "Object not set to an instance", I do not know what do I need to initialize.

If someone can give me a hint. I appreciate it.

```
    public string GetEmail(string userId)
    {

        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, MyDomain);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userId);
        return user.EmailAddress;
    }
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception. Could you provide stack trace as well?

Comment: I like the mystery inherent in his question!  This would make a great interview question, "Guess where the exception is being thrown!"

Comment: I'm getting the error on the last line,

Comment: This means the user you were looking for cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you @botond.botos I'm going to investigate!

Comment: Done guys, user was null, I changed the IdentityType.SamAccountName to DistinguishedName and that's it! (Y)